# ArrayList input and output in Java

Tags: java

I have a program that needs to meet these specifications:
    • A salesperson will continue to earn a fixed salary of $50,000.00 per year. The current sales target for every salesperson is $120,000.00 per year.
     
    • The sales incentive will only start when 80% of the sales target is met. The current commission is 7.5% of total sales.
     
    • If a salesperson exceeds the sales target, the commission will increase based on an acceleration factor. The acceleration factor is 1.25.
     
    • The application should ask the user to enter annual sales, and it should display the total annual compensation.
     
    • The application should also display a table of potential total annual compensation that the salesperson could have earned, in $5000 increments above the salesperson’s annual sales, until it reaches 50% above the salesperson’s annual sales.

```
• The application will now compare the total annual compensation of at least two salespersons.
 
• It will calculate the additional amount of sales that each salesperson must achieve to match or exceed the higher of the two earners.
 
• The application should ask for the name of each salesperson being compared. 
• The application should have at least one class, in addition to the application’s controlling class.
• The source code must demonstrate the use of conditional and looping structures.
• The source code must demonstrate the use of Array or ArrayList.
```

There should be proper documentation in the source code

I was able to construct the table with a while loop. My problem now is the array or ArrayList.  I constructed an ArrayList with a Salesperson class, but it is not output the getName. What am I doing wrong? Below are my codes.

```
/*
 * Program: Salesperson.java
 * Written by: Amy Morin
 * This program will calculate total annual compensation for a salesperson.
 * Business requirements include:
 * Fixed salary = $50,000, sales target = $120,000,
 * sales incentive at 80% of sales,
 * Commission 7.5% of sales, if sales target is exceeded 1.25% increased 
 * accelorated factor.
 * This program will also be the foundation to
 * compare two or more salespersons.
 */

public class Salesperson
{   
    //Declares and initalizes fixed salary.
    private final double Fix_Sal = 50000;
    //Declares and initalizes commission.
    private final double Comm = 7.5;
    //Declares and initalizes acceleration factor.
    private final double Accel_Factor = 1.25;
    //Declares and initializes sales target.
    double target = 120000;         
    //Declares and initializes sales incentive threshold.
    double thresh = .80;

    String spName;    //holds the salesperson's name
    double annSales;   // Holds value for annual sales
    double commRate;  //holds calculated commission rate.  
    double commEarned;  //holds calculated commission earned.   
    double totalAnnComp; //Holds calculated total annual commission

    //Default Constructor
    public Salesperson()
    {
        spName = "Unknown";
        annSales = 0.0;
    }

    ////parameterized constructor
    public Salesperson(String name, double sales)
    {
        spName = name;
        annSales = sales;
    }

    //The setName method will set the name of salesperson
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        name = spName;
    }

    //The getName method will ruturn the name of salesperson
    public String getName()
    {
        return spName;
    }

    //The setSales method will set the annual sales
    public void setSales(double sales)
    {
        annSales = sales;
    }

    //The getSales method returns the value stored in annualSales
    public double getSales()
    {
        return annSales;
    }

    //The getComm method will calculate and return commission earned
    public double getComm()
    {
    //Check if sale are greater than or equal to 80% of target. 
    if (annSales >= (target * thresh))
    {
            if (annSales > target) //Checks if annual sales exceed target.
            {   
            //Gets commission rate.
                commRate = (Comm * Accel_Factor)/100;
        commEarned = commRate * annSales;
            }
            else
            {
        commRate = Comm/100;
        commEarned = commRate * annSales;
            }
    }
    else
        {
        commRate = 0;
        commEarned = 0;
    }
    return commEarned;
    }

    /*
     * The getAnnComp method will calculate and return the total 
     * annual compensation.
     */ 
    public double getAnnComp ()
    {
    totalAnnComp = Fix_Sal + commEarned;
    return totalAnnComp;
    }
}


/*
 * Program: SalespersonComparison
 * Written by: Amy Morin
 * This program will compare the total annual compensation 
 * of at least two salespersons. It will also calculate the additional 
 * amount of sales that each salesperson must achieve to match or 
 * exceed the higher of the two earners.
 */

import java.util.ArrayList; //Needed for ArrayList
import java.util.Scanner;  //Needed for Scanner class
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //Needed for Decimal formatting

public class SalespersonComparison
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {         
       final double Fix_Sal = 50000; //Declares and initiates fixed salary
       double sales; // hold annual sales

       //Create new ArrayList
       ArrayList<Salesperson> cArray = new ArrayList<>();

        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

       //Lets user know how to end loop
       System.out.println("Press \'Enter\' to continue or type \'done\'"
               + " when finished.");

       //blank line
       System.out.println();

       //Loop for setting name and annual sales of salesperson
       do
       {   
           //Create an Salesperson object
           Salesperson sPerson = new Salesperson();

           //Set salesperson's name
           System.out.println("Enter salesperson name");
           String name = keyboard.nextLine();
           sPerson.setName(name);

           //End while loop
           if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Done"))
               break;                     

           //Set annual sales for salesperson
           System.out.println("Enter annual sales for salesperson");
           sales = keyboard.nextDouble();
           sPerson.setSales(sales);          

           //To add Salesperson object to ArrayList
           cArray.add(sPerson);

           //Consume line
           keyboard.nextLine();     
       }
       while (true);

       //Display ArrayList

       DecimalFormat arrayL = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
       for (int index = 0; index < cArray.size(); index++)
       {
           Salesperson sPerson = (Salesperson)cArray.get(index);
           System.out.println();
           System.out.print("Salesperson " + (index + 1) +
                            "\n Name: " + sPerson.getName() +
                            "\n Sales: " + (arrayL.format(sPerson.getSales())) +
                            "\n Commission Earned: " + 
                            (arrayL.format(sPerson.getComm())) +
                            "\n Total Annual Compensation: " 
                            + (arrayL.format(sPerson.getAnnComp())) + "\n\n");



       }
   }
}      

Output
Press 'Enter' to continue or type 'done' when finished.

Enter salesperson name
amy
Enter annual sales for salesperson
100000
Enter salesperson name
marty
Enter annual sales for salesperson
80000
Enter salesperson name
done

Salesperson 1
 Name: Unknown
 Sales: 100,000.00
 Commission Earned: 7,500.00
 Total Annual Compensation: 57,500.00


Salesperson 2
 Name: Unknown
 Sales: 80,000.00
 Commission Earned: 0.00
 Total Annual Compensation: 50,000.00

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)
```

Once I figure this problem out then I need figure out how to add the table and do the comparison.

Comment: Your question is too long. Go straight to the point, only paste the relevant code, and explain clearly what this relevant code is supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: This is clearly a homework problem--so I'm not going to answer directly.  But examine your getters and settings.

Comment: Everybody has pretty much already given you the answer, but as @JerryAndrews points out, the issue is with your getters and setters.  This would been an excellent opportunity to use a debugger ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the values in the opposite order.

```
//The setName method will set the name of salesperson
public void setName(String name)
{
    name = spName;
}
```

Should be

```
//The setName method will set the name of salesperson
public void setName(String name)
{
    spName = name;
}
```

Comment: user1681360, thank you, I did not even notice this simple little mistake, sometimes it takes fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your setter method:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    name = spName;
}
```

You're assigning the attribute to the variable. Fix it like this:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.spName = name;
}
```

To avoid this kind of problems, remember to use `this` keyword in your getters and to assign the parameter to the attribute.

Comment: Making the parameters final can also help detect this kind of bugs.

Comment: This worked, Luiggi Mendoza, thank you. Can you explain to me the meaning of the this.